# JBoss(WildFly) doesn't detect css files for index.html

Tags: html, css, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

Here is my directory structure.

```
WebContent
    META-INF
    WEB-INF
    WebSites
        Index
            index.html
            css
                animate.css
```

In `web.xml` I specified `welcome-file` list as >/WebSites/Index/index.html.
Then the html is loaded without any style.
When I place the css folder in `WebContents` folder the style is loaded without any modification in `web.xml`. Is there a way I can fix this ?

Comment: Can you put the index.html fragment with the declaration of the css?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
 <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Will it be solved if i change this to "./css/animate.css" ??

Comment: i tried "./css/animate.css" and "/Websites/Index/css/animate.css" but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used "/Test/WebSites/Index/css/animate.css" and it worked(Test is my project name). For giving a link to another page also, i followed same format. I don't know why but this worked.